# German real-estate. Property caveat when company goes bankrupt

Tags: germany, real-estate

I bought an apartment in germany in a building that hasn't been built yet.
I have also applied for and received a 'property caveat'. What happens if the company that i bought the apartment from goes bankrupt?.
I mean does my property caveat stay even for other companies that will later on take this? Can those companies ignore/remove my caveat?

Comment: what's the term in the contract you signed?

Comment: What is the legal German term for 'property caveat' in your contract? Searching the English term gives good answers to what this means in English language jurisdictions but I would rather not just assume it is exactly the same in Germany.